# Save long directory path to local variable in Apache Drill?

Tags: apache-drill

With Apache Drill, when querying files from the filesystem, is there any way to set a shortcut for long directory paths?

For example, in:

```
> SELECT * FROM dfs.`/Users/me/Clients/foo/current-data/sample/releases/test*.json`
```

Is there any way I can shorten `/Users/me/Dropbox/Clients/foo/current-data/sample/releases/` to a local variable so I don't have to type the full path each time?

I've looked through [the docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-directories/), but can't see any reference to this (but maybe I'm being dumb).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options here:

1. You could create a view from you long query so you don't have to type the monstrosity every time. This is less flexible then the second solution. For more information, check out: https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-view
2. You could modify the DFS storage settings (in the web ui at http://:8047 under the storage tab/dfs) and create a new workspaces pointing directly to the "/Users/me/Clients/foo/current-data/sample/releases" directory.

For example:
    "releases": {
      "location": 
      "/mapr/demo.mapr.com/data/a/university/student/records/grades/",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    }

Then you would be able to query select * from `dfs.releases`.`tests.csv`